# perl script Use of uninitialized value error

Tags: perl

I have this perl script that alters MySQL database data, everytime I run it I get the following error

```
 Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at ./cdr_db.pl-m line 88.
```

Looking at the code from line 80 to 88

```
### archive cdr records
    $sth = $dbh2->prepare(
        "SELECT max($tablename2_archive.EventID) from $tablename2_archive")
      or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
    $sth->execute()
      or die
"Database error trying to poll $tablename2_archive.EventID for archive use: "
      . $sth->errstr . "\n";
    my $nextEventID = $sth->fetchrow_array + 1;
```

here is the full script

http://pastebin.com/4hmaS3b9

I just don't get what the error is.

Comment: It looks as though `$sth->fetchrow_array` is `undef`. Use `Data::Dumper` to take a closer look at `$sth` and `$sth->fetchrow_array`. Try `print`ing out the query (after the variables are filled in) and see if there are any problems with it.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that since `$sth->fetchrow_array` is an array, you're calling it in a scalar context when you add 1 to it...

Comment: @JackManey: Despite its identifier `fetchrow_array` returns a *list*, which is a [very different thing](http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perlfaq4-dataarrays.html) from an array.

Comment: @Borodin - [checks docs] Right you are. My apologies, I usually use `fetchrow_arrayref` or `fetch` with bound parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchrow_array` returns a *list* of values, which is empty if there are no more rows to be fetched.

Adding one to a list is bad Perl style, but it has the effect of using the *last* element of the list, which is what you want here since there should be only a single return value.

As it stands, `fetchrow_array` could be returning either an empty list or a list ending with `undef`. Both would evaluate as `undef` in the addition. The first is most likely, and I guess you are trying to add a record to an empty table, when there is no previous `EventID` column?

You should write

```
$sth->execute;
my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array;
die "No results returned" unless @row;
my $nextEventID = $row[0] + 1;
```

or it would be much nicer (and faster, for what it's worth) to bind the column you are fetching

```
my $eventID;

$sth->execute;
$sth->bind_columns(\$eventID);
$sth->fetch;
die "No results returned" unless defined $eventID;
my $nextEventID = $eventID + 1;
```

But you will still have to check whether `$eventID` is `undef` before you do the arithmetic.

Lastly. Sorry this is so long-winded, you should make the `EventID` column `NOT NULL` so that you can be sure a value of `undef` indicates that no rows have been found, and you should make use of the MySQL `AUTO_INCREMENT` column property so that you don't have to calculate the IDs yourself. The declaration would look like

```
EventID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

and you would just omit a value for that column when you write your `INSERT INTO`.

I hope this helps.